# Why am I getting browser message when loading localhost websites

Tags: php, wordpress, http, browser

I'm having a problem with two localhost programs InstantWP and Laragon loading in the Chrome browser. I keep getting the message below:

**This site can’t be reached The web page at http://127.0.0.1:10080/wordpress/wp-login.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT**

I've read and read about this and have done everything suggested online regarding browsers but to no avail.

I tried them on other browsers and InstantWP on another laptop but when I try and load it I get the same browser message.

I think not know that the issue is because my sites are http and the browser wants them to have be https. Strange thing is if a start a new wpsite in Laragon it works fine but my site is in file form.

I followed the instructions loaded the database and put the other files in a folder in .www but when I try to load it I get the same as with InstantWP, the message in bold above.

I've put hundreds of hours into my sites and don't want to lose them.

Any help and advice given will be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: The OP might have found the solution, but for future visitors to this question, here gets a note: as of version 91, Chrome has blocked HTTP port 10080 (see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6510270304223232), so better use another port, or explicitly allow this port by passing parameter `--explicitly-allowed-ports=10080` when launching Chrome.